# GCE - old version of system being called although a new version is deployed

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I have a system running on a Debian virtual machine on Google Compute Engine.

It's a Java web application running on Tomcat. I deployed this system almost a year ago and it's been running fine.

I deployed a new version about a month ago. I did so solely by replacing the `.war` file with the new one.

I very recently noticed that, on some calls to the web address, say `http://www.example.com`, the old version of the system is taking up the call. 
The way it seems, the `http://www.example.com` calls are made to the new, `http://example.com` are made to the old version of my system.

Note - there's no question about this "*two different – old and new versions running on different calls*". I'm making the system tell me things in certain situations. I recognize them by the messages they send me – the old and new versions use different "wording" on these.

The likeliest scenario is - not all the replicas of my system up there in the Google Cloud are refreshed with the version I last deployed.

I am now writing to find out what this is– the cause, and how to attack it. Google is asking for support account which i don't have (/yet), and there doesn't seem to be other resources.  I'm looking to have an idea at this stage.